# Python generate a mask for the lower triangle of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, seaborn

I have this code from seaborn documentation to generate a mask for the upper triangle of a given correlation matrix

```
# Compute the correlation matrix
corr = d.corr()

# Generate a mask for the upper triangle

mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
```

how would one achieve the invert, a mask for the lower triangle?

Comment: Please, could you share corr?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply replace `triu_indices_from` with `tril_indices_from`:

```
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.tril_indices_from(mask)] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the transpose of your matrix:

```
mask = mask.T

mask
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])

mask.T
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

However this is more of a workaround, the correct solution is @john 's

Answer (score 1):

You can simply transpose the mask that you have:

```
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool).T
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
```