# Adjusting width of subplots on seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

After coming across this: [Combining two heat maps in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272437/combining-two-heat-maps-in-seaborn) I did the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8,1), columns=list("A"))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8,1), columns=list("B"))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8,4), columns=list("CDEF"))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8,1), columns=list("G"))
df5 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8,1), columns=list("H"))

fig, (ax, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5) = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 10), ncols=5)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.01)

sb.heatmap(df,  ax=ax, cbar=False, cmap = 'coolwarm_r', vmax = 30, vmin = 10, annot = True, fmt = '.2f', annot_kws = {'size':12})
sb.heatmap(df2, ax=ax2, cbar=False, cmap = 'coolwarm_r', vmax = 20, vmin = -10, annot = True, fmt = '.2f', annot_kws = {'size':12})
sb.heatmap(df3, ax=ax3, cbar=False, cmap = 'coolwarm_r', vmax = 50, vmin = 30, annot = True, fmt = '.2f', annot_kws = {'size':12})
sb.heatmap(df4, ax=ax4, cbar=False, cmap = 'coolwarm_r', vmax = 10, vmin = 5, annot = True, fmt = '.2f', annot_kws = {'size':12})
sb.heatmap(df5, ax=ax5, cbar=False, cmap = 'coolwarm_r', vmax = 8, vmin = 2, annot = True, fmt = '.2f', annot_kws = {'size':12})

ax2.set_yticks([])
ax3.set_yticks([])
ax4.set_yticks([])
ax5.set_yticks([])

ax.xaxis.tick_top()  # Put x axis on top
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()  # Put x axis on top
ax3.xaxis.tick_top()  # Put x axis on top
ax4.xaxis.tick_top()  # Put x axis on top
ax5.xaxis.tick_top()  # Put x axis on top

fig.colorbar(ax5.collections[0], ax=ax5, location="right", use_gridspec=False, pad=0.2)
ax.tick_params(rotation=0)  # Do not rotate y tick labels

plt.show()
```

But I get the following output where the width of each column of the heatmap is not the same:

[image]

Is there any way to resize each column (including those 4 columns from that one df in the middle) so that they're all of the same width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'width_ratios'` of `plt.subplot`'s `gridspec_kw` sets the ratios between the axes. Note that adding the colorbar to `ax5` will take away some of its space which would make it smaller. Therefore, it's easier to create an additional `ax` for the colorbar. As the axes are very close to each other, a dummy ax can be added to create some padding.
As the colorbar ticks only refer to `ax5`, an idea is to remove them with `fig.colorbar(..., ticks=[])`.

The code can be a bit easier to maintain using loops.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8, 1) * 50, columns=list("A"))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8, 1) * 50, columns=list("B"))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8, 4) * 50, columns=list("CDEF"))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8, 1) * 50, columns=list("G"))
df5 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8, 1) * 50, columns=list("H"))

dfs = [df, df2, df3, df4, df5]
widths = [len(d.columns) for d in dfs]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 7), ncols=7,
                         gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.01, 'width_ratios': widths + [0.2, 0.1]})

for ax, dfi, vmin, vmax in zip(axes[:len(dfs)], dfs, [10, -10, 30, 5, 2], [30, 20, 50, 10, 8]):
    sns.heatmap(dfi, ax=ax, cbar=False, cmap='coolwarm_r', vmax=vmax, vmin=vmin, annot=True, fmt='.2f',
                annot_kws={'size': 12})
    ax.xaxis.tick_top()  # Put x axis on top
    ax.tick_params(rotation=0)  # Do not rotate y tick labels
    if ax != axes[0]:
        ax.set_yticks([])

fig.colorbar(ax5.collections[0], cax=axes[-1])
axes[-2].axis('off')  # turn dummy as off

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped my with something else, but shouldn't it be `gridspec_kws`, not `gridspec_kw`? That's what worked for me.

Comment: Well, the [official doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) only mentions `gridspec_kw`. Not to be confused with seaborn's [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), which does use `gridspec_kws`.

Comment: That explains it. I was using FacetGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't fully understand your question, but what about combining all the data frames and drawing a heat map?[image]

```
df_new = pd.concat([df,df2,df3,df4,df5],axis=1)

sb.heatmap(df_new,  ax=ax, cbar=True, cmap = 'coolwarm_r', annot = True, fmt = '.2f', annot_kws = {'size':12})
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I edited my answer taking out some details thinking it was irrelevant but it's actually pretty relevant - basically for each df I want to define a different vmax and vmin, which is why I wanted to do the separate subplots in the first place